# Relizar resta a una variable en una cadena de texto en PHP (Curiosidad)

Tags: php, string, variables, operador, procesamiento-de-texto

quisiera saber si es posible obtener este resultado:

La resta de 5-1 es igual a 4

Se que si hago esto lo puedo obtener:

```
$numero = 5;
$numero2 = 1;

$resultado = $numero - $numero2;

echo "La resta de 5-1 es igual a $resultado";
```

Pero yo quiero obtener ese resultado realizando algo como esto(se que está mal pero es para que me entiendan)

```
$numero =5;

echo "La resta de 5-1 es igual a $numero-1";
```

Quisiera saber si es posible hacer algo como eso.

También saber si es posible realizar una resta de números en la cadena de manera similar a como lo expresé antes, por ejemplo:

```
echo "La resta de 5-1 es igual a 5-1(y que me de 4)";
```

Es una curiosidad que tenía.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo primero si funciona y si que me da el resultado, correcto. Los otros 2 ejemplos es lo que trato de averiguar si puedo obtener el mismo resultado del primero de arriba.

Comment: Si, efectivamente, lo probé y funciona, muchas gracias.

Comment: En estos casos sería bueno tal vez proveer tu comentario como respuesta @Triby así evitamos que la pregunta quede huérfana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En PHP no se pueden realizar operaciones con variables dentro de cadenas, por ejemplo:

```
$num = 5;
echo "Resta = $num - 1"; // Resta = 5 - 1
```

PHP solo interpreta la variable, sin realizar operaciones.

Cosas que sí funcionan: Concatenar o uso de funciones de remplazo como [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf)

```
$num = 5;
echo "Resta = " . ($num - 1); // Resta = 4
echo sprintf("Resta = %d", $num - 1); // Resta = 4
```